# How do I store values from a method into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently making a game in java in which I have 7 rows. Each of these rows has a designated score and can be calculated with the method: `calculateRowScore(int row)`. This method works fine, but what I am having trouble with is finding the calculate the maximum score from all rows with the method: `calculateMaxScore()`

This is the code I have for it currently:

```
public static int calculateMaxScore()
            {
               for(int row=1; row<8; row++)
               {
                 int rowscore = calculateRowScore(row);
               }

               return 0; 
            }
```

My question is how do I return each of the 7 scores I get from the `calculateRowScore(row)` which are all stored in `rowscore` into an array from which I can calculate the maximum value out of the 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to calculate the max score directly instead of putting everything into an array:

```
public static int calculateMaxScore() {
    int rowscore = 0;
     for(int row=1; row<8; row++)
     {
        if (calculateRowScore(row) > rowscore) {
          rowscore = calculateRowScore(row);
        }
     }
     return rowscore; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static int[] calculateRowScores() {
    int[] rowscores = new int[8];
    for(int row=1; row<8; row++) {
        rowscores[row] = calculateRowScore(row);
    }
    return rowscores; 
}
```

To find the max in the method:

```
public static int calculateMaxScore() {
    return IntStream.range(0, 8).map(this::calculateRowScore).max();
}
```

Comment: You really should use `rowscores.length` or create a `magic number`.

Comment: @Oliver OP used `8`, so I did too. Not having magic numbers in code is good advice, but that advice is not needed to answer this qusestion (and given OP is new to programming, not desirable due to extra confusion it would cause).

Comment: i already found an alternate solution, but this works great too! thank you :)